# .netcore 1.1 "assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a working .netcore 1.1 app running with net451.
I changed the target framework to net462, cleared out bin/nuget packages, rebuilt everything/dotnet restore and it compiled fine.
When I access a method from the `System.Http.Net` library, the app throws the following exception.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
>   'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51    at
>   System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)

How do I further debug this issue?  I'm using win10-x64 and vs2017 RC.

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Benni The issue disappeared at some point. I'm not sure what fixed it - probably upgrading to latest .netcore tools / vs2017rc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After updating [.Net Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd) to the latest version, the problem has been disappeared.